# Django: logging or send errors by mail

Tags: django, logging

I would like to know if there is a simple way to configure django in order that the error page of the debug mode is sent to the admin by mail.

It would be even better to use [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) but how can you add a error to your logger if it raised by django itself (ad not one of your views)?

I've check the [logging facility of the development version](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-s-logging-extensions) but I'm running Django 1.2.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is built in. Just add your email address to `ADMINS` in settings.py. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/error-reporting/).